# 80s-90s movie about a boy abducted by an alien, replaced by a robot version of himself

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched a movie when I was little about a boy who was abducted by an alien (maybe by choice I'm not sure) but while he was abducted, they sent an alien or robot version of himself to take his place so his family did not know.

I also remember a part where the brother of the abducted kid saw the robot/alien version of his brother at night and the alien/robot was fixing his wiring inside of his head or something and he told the brother that it was all a dream and to go back to sleep.

I think that the alien place that the boy was in was like an all-white building with stars or something outside and I think one of the alien people had red or green hair.

I think it is an 80s or 90s movie but not positive.

Comment: Welcome Elizabeth.  While the answers are the same, the questions most definitely are not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Almost certain this is *The Last Starfighter* (1984).

Not really remembering the red or green hair but the building IIRC was built on some kind of moon, and had an exterior shot where you could see the stars and the robot fixing his head and telling the brother to go back to sleep is probably somewhat unique.